# snmptrapd doesn't log in mysql

Tags: mysql, debian, net-snmp, snmptrapd

I am trying to log snmp traps to mysql db, but unfortunately without results.
OS - Debian
Net-SNMP v.5.7.3
MySQL 5.1
I am using snmptrapd and did the configuration from [here](http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/Snmptrapd)

here is my snmptrapd.conf:

```
authCommunity log public
sqlMaxQueue 1
sqlSaveInterval 9
```

I did

`./configure --with-defaults --with-mysql`

as in the manual . Then

```
make
make install
```

Here is my ~/.my.cnf:

```
[snmptrapd]
user=snmp
password=******
host=localhost
```

my /default/snmpd:

```
#export MIBS=
#SNMPDRUN=yes    
#SNMPDOPTS='-Lsd -Lf /dev/null -u snmp -g snmp -I -smux -p /var/run/snmpd.pid'    
TRAPDRUN=yes    
TRAPDOPTS='-Lsd -p /var/run/snmptrapd.pid'    
SNMPDCOMPAT=yes
```

I  have exact DB schema as in the manual

I have success logging into syslog, but nothing in mysql. Even mysql log doesn't show anything. It's looks like snmptrapd doesnt reach MySQL

Can anyone give me idea what i am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution of my problem. 
I have been changing `/etc/snmp/snmptrapd.conf` and mysql logging didnt worked. I just find that there is another `snmptrapd.conf` in `/usr/local/etc/snmp/snmptrapd.conf` that i fill with the configuration showed in my first post. 
So far it works!

Answer (score 0):

I have found an article for you:

http://ethertype.blogspot.com/2015/10/logging-snmp-traps-to-mysqlmariadb.html

You must set your database name as "net_snmp".